# Delete entities related by ManyToMany relationships, when one side is deleted: Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a scenario with two **ManyToMany** relationships. I have following entities-

1. InsurancePolicy - hold policy details
2. County -hold the country/state details
3. PolicyCounty (entity maintaining ManyToMany relationship between InsurancePolicy and County, and an additional attribute in this relationship is cost).
4. User -hold user details (has One To Many relationship with UserPolicyQuery)
5. UserPolicyQuery (this has a many to many relationship with PolicyCounty).
   Here is the code-

**User-**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column (name ="userid" )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userId;

    @Column(name="firstname",nullable = false)
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name="lastname",nullable = false)
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "useremail",nullable = false)
    private String email;



    @Column(name = "phonenumber",nullable = false)
    private long phoneNumber;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserPolicyQuery> userPolicyQueries = new HashSet<>();


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UserPolicyQuery-**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="user_policy_query")
public class UserPolicyQuery {

    @Id
    @Column(name="query_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long queryId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="query_policy_county",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="query", referencedColumnName = "query_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="policy_county", referencedColumnName = "policy_county_id"))
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=new HashSet<>();


    @Column(name="comment",nullable = true)
    private String comment;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPolicyQuery{" +
                "queryId=" + queryId +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**PolicyCounty-**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_county")
public class PolicyCounty {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_county_id")
    private long policyCountyId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="policy_id")
    private InsurancePolicy policy;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "county_id")
    private County county;

    @Column(name="cost",nullable = false)
    private double cost;





    public long getPolicyCountyId() {
        return policyCountyId;
    }

    public InsurancePolicy getPolicy() {
        System.out.println("Policy County: getPolicy() called");
        return policy;
    }

    public County getCounty() {
        System.out.println("Policy county: getCounty() called");
        return county;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

and **InsurancePolicy-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_policy")
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InsurancePolicy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_id")
    private long policyId;

    @Column(name="policy_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String policyName;

    //Short description
    @Column(name="policy_description",nullable = false)
    private String policyDescription;

    //Long description
    @Column(name="choose_description",nullable = false)
    private String chooseDescription;


    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",nullable=false)
    private Category category;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();

    public long getPolicyId() {
        return policyId;
    }

    public String getPolicyName() {
        return policyName;
    }

    public String getPolicyDescription() {
        return policyDescription;
    }

    public String getChooseDescription() {
        return chooseDescription;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        System.out.println("InsurancePolicy.getCompany() called");
        return company;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }


    public Set<PolicyCounty> getPolicyCounties() {
        System.out.println("Insurance policy getPolicyCounties called");
        return policyCounties;
    }
}
```

Now, my requirement is-

1. When I delete an **InsurancePolicy**, I need to delete the corresponding **PolicyCounty** (I have achieved till here), and also delete any mapping of **UserPolicyQueries which are referencing the **PolicyCounties** (i.e., I have to delete the record that a particular **UserPolicyQuery** is associated with the **PolicyCounty** (which is getting deleted).
2. When a **User** or **UserPolicyQuery** is deleted, the mappings with **PolicyCounty** must be deleted, but not the **PolicyCounties**.
3. In case a company is deleted, all its policies will have to be deleted and thus, all its associated **PolicyCounty** and **UserPolicyQueries** mappings will have to be deleted.

In short, I want to delete the relationship between **PolicyCounty** and **UserPolicyQuery** which is held by the table **query_policy_county** when policy is deleted (or **PolicyCounty** is deleted) and don't delete the **PolicyCounties** when query is deleted.
Due to two ManyToMany relationships, I am not quite not able to understand what exactly to do in this case. Please help!

Comment: You are looking for `cascade`. I'd expect that `@ManyToMany` and `@ManyToOne` allow you to configure it.

Comment: Thank You for pointing it out. Actually I need to delete the Many to Many relationship between PolicyCounty and the UserPolicyQuery table which is established by the query_policy_county table.

Comment: This is because a UserPolicyQuery might be associated with some other PolicyCounties which are not getting deleted. I have slightly changed the description in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to:

1. In `PolicyCounty`, just add a `UserPolicyQuery` relationship with `orphanRemoval=true` - this deletes queries when their associated PolicyCounty is deleted
2. In `UserPolicyQuery` you need to remove `CascadeType.REMOVE` from the `PolicyCounty` relationship, since this prevents deletion of `PolicyCounty` when the query is deleted (!)
3. In `Company`, add `CascadeType.REMOVE` to `InsurancePolicy` join - this deletes policies and associated `PolicyCounty` and `UserPolicyQueries` when a company is deleted

So you'll get something like:

```java
// `PolicyCounty`
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "policyCounty", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<UserPolicyQuery> userPolicyQueries = new HashSet<>();
```

```java
// `UserPolicyQuery`
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="query_policy_county",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="query", referencedColumnName = "query_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="policy_county", referencedColumnName = "policy_county_id"))
private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();
```

```
// `Company`
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<InsurancePolicy> insurancePolicies = new HashSet<>();
```

**UPD:**
You may also use an `Entity Listener` to perform the manual deletion of the relationships, kinda:

```java
public class PolicyCountyListener {

    @PostRemove
    public void postRemove(PolicyCounty policyCounty) {
        for (UserPolicyQuery userPolicyQuery: policyCounty.getUserPolicyQueries()) {
            userPolicyQuery.getPolicyCounties().remove(policyCounty);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@EntityListeners(PolicyCountyListener.class)
public class PolicyCounty {
...
```

So when a `PolicyCounty` entity is deleted, it will automaticaly remove its associations with UserPolicyQuery entities as well, but not delete those entities completely

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, but I don't want to delete the UserPolicyQuery, I just want to delete the relationship between UserPolicyQuery and PolicyCounty. This is beacuse the query might be related to some other PolicyCounty entities which are not getting deleted.

Comment: Are you aware of Entity Listener then? Let me update my answer

Comment: No, I am not aware of Entity Listener. Can you please help in this regard!

Comment: you may try updated one

Comment: Thank You. I will try it. One thing more, I don't have Set<UserPolicyQuery> userPolicyQueries(), in my PolicyCounty class. I only have unidirectional relationship from UserPolicyQuerySide. Also, why have you used OneToMany in PolicyCounty but ManyToMany in UserPolicyQuery?